# Editing A WCF service after I have it on a server

Tags: .net, wcf

I have uploaded a web service onto IIS 7 and I just realized I am going to need to change up some of the functionality to get it to work.  I figured I just compile the dll onto my machine and copy it over the server... My question is would I need to Refresh the service reference in my client application that is using it currently to make sure that I get the latest functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well it depends on what you are changing in your service. If you are not changing service method names or changing the arguments of the service methods you do not need to refresh the client.

But if you make these kinds of changes you have to refresh the client

Comment: That's what I suspected.  Thanks for the help.